# Show that $6x + 5 \equiv 7 \pmod 5$ has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $u$ be a solution to $6x + 5 \equiv 7 \pmod 5$ so that $6u + 5 \equiv 7 \pmod 5$. Then there's some $t$ such that $u \equiv t \pmod 5$.

Then
$$6u \equiv t \pmod 5,$$
$$6u + 5 \equiv t + 5 \pmod 5,$$
$$7 \equiv t + 5 \pmod 5,$$
$$t + 5 \equiv 6t + 5 \pmod 5,$$
$$0 \equiv 5t \pmod 5.$$

Can we say that since $7 \equiv 6t + 5 \pmod 5$ and $0 \equiv 5t \pmod 5$ are equivalent(?), then $7 \equiv 6t + 5 \pmod 5$ has infinite number of solutions?

Comment: If you reduce the coefficients of your equation modulo 5, you get $x=1$ mod 5. It's easier to find solutions if this equation.

Comment: If $x$ is a solution, then $x+5k$ is a solution.

Comment: Do you mean $u+5k$?

Comment: @ copper.hat, Suppose $6u + 5 = 7 \pmod 3$ holds. Would that mean $u + 3k$ also a solution for any $k$?

Comment: @user273143: The statement $6u + 5 = 7 \pmod 3$ can never hold, so the answer is a vacuous yes.

Comment: @ copper.hat, where does the solution $x + 5k$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a lot of misunderstandings here. Let me adress a few:

1. The statement

   *"Then there's some $t$ such that $u=t\pmod5$."*

   is completely void; for every $u$ we can simply take $t=u$ to get $u=t\pmod5$.
2. The implication
   $$6u + 5 = t + 5 \pmod 5\qquad\to\qquad 7 = t + 5 \pmod 5,$$
   is simply false, even assuming $u\equiv t\pmod5$. Take $u=t=0$, for example.
3. The implication
   $$7 = t + 5 \pmod 5\qquad\to\qquad t + 5 = 6t + 5 \pmod 5,$$
   is also completely void; the latter is true regardless of the former.
4. The same goes for the implication
   $$t + 5 = 6t + 5 \pmod 5\qquad\to\qquad0 = 5t \pmod 5.$$
5. The statements $7 = 6t + 5 \pmod 5$ and $0=5t\pmod5$ are *not* equivalent. Take $t=0$ for example.
6. And from the previous point, I cannot see any reason to believe that it follows that there are infinitely many solutions to $7=6t+5\pmod5$.

**Suggestion:** Look up what $a\equiv b\pmod c$ means for integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $c>0$. Then try proving that if $x$ is a solution to $6x+5=7\pmod5$, also $x+5k$ is a solution for any integer $k$.

Comment: I am supposed to use 1) if $u = v \pmod n$ and $u$ is a solution of $6x + 5 = 7 \pmod n$, then $v$ is also a solution. 2) If $6x + 5 = 7 \pmod n$ has a solution, then one of $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n - 1$ is also a solution. Am I being asked to do as you suggested? I am trying to go by the book :)

Comment: Your first point is equivalent to what I suggest you prove. It is not necessary to prove or use your second point, but it is handy for finding a solution.

Comment: $u = v \pmod 5 \to 6u = 6v \pmod 5 \to 6u + 5 = 6v + 5 \pmod 5 \to 7  = 6v + 5 \pmod 5 \to 7 = 6(v + 5k) + 5 \pmod 5$. Since $5 \mid 7 – 6v + 5$ and $5 \mid 30k$, then $5 \mid 7 – 6v + 30k + 5$. So, $v + 5k$ is a solution. Do you agree?